# Creating an XSL file that loops through XML

Tags: xml, loops, xslt

I am trying to create a XSL file that loops through this XML file.

XML:

```
<ArrayOfCourse xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Demo.Samples" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<Course>
<codeField>COMPSCI 101</codeField>
<semesterField>Summer School; Semester 1; Semester 2</semesterField>
<titleField>Principles of Programming</titleField>
</Course>
</ArrayOfCourse>
```

this is what I came up with, which works fine if I change the ArrayOfCourse tag to `<ArrayOfCourse>` (removing the xmlns).

XSL:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
    <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
          xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" >

      <xsl:template match="/">
        <HTML>
          <BODY>
              <xsl:for-each select="ArrayOfCourse/Course">
                <xsl:sort select="state" order="descending"/>
                <xsl:sort select="name"/>
                <xsl:value-of select="codeField" />:
                <b><xsl:value-of select="titleField" /> </b><br/>
                <xsl:value-of select="semesterField" /> <br/><br/>
              </xsl:for-each>
          </BODY>
        </HTML>
      </xsl:template>

    </xsl:stylesheet>
```

What can I do to make it work properly with the `xmlns="..."` part still in the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're using XSLT 1.0, you need to either:

- Declare the namespace with a prefix and use the prefix in your xpaths. (**recommended**)

or

- Use `local-name()` and `namespace-uri()` (optional) in a predicate. (Example: `*[local-name()='Course']`.

Example of your XSLT with the namespace declared with the prefix `ds` (prefix can be anything and does not need to match the prefix in the input (if there was one)):

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:ds="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Demo.Samples"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" >

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <HTML>
            <BODY>
                <xsl:for-each select="ds:ArrayOfCourse/ds:Course">
                    <xsl:sort select="ds:state" order="descending"/>
                    <xsl:sort select="ds:name"/>
                    <xsl:value-of select="ds:codeField" />:
                    <b><xsl:value-of select="ds:titleField" /> </b><br/>
                    <xsl:value-of select="ds:semesterField" /> <br/><br/>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </BODY>
        </HTML>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Google `xslt default namespace` for more info.